# Android ImageView.draw() leaves a trail

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm implementing image cropping feature.

I'm drawing crop rectangle and highlight like in code sample below. This aproach works fine with android 2.x.x. But With 4.x I had to turn of hardware accelaration because `Canvas.clipPath` did not worked as expected.

After that I get these trails. I'm kind of new to canvas and I'd appreciate any help.

Code sample

```
Rect viewDrawingRect = new Rect();
imageView.getDrawingRect(viewDrawingRect);

path.addRect(new RectF(drawRect), Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
canvas.drawRect(viewDrawingRect, hasFocus() ? focusPaint : noFocusPaint);

canvas.restore();
canvas.drawPath(path, outlinePaint);

int left = drawRect.left;
int right = drawRect.right;
int top = drawRect.top;
int bottom = drawRect.bottom;

int widthWidth = resizeDrawableWidth.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
int widthHeight = resizeDrawableWidth.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
int heightHeight = resizeDrawableHeight.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
int heightWidth = resizeDrawableHeight.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;

int xMiddle = drawRect.left + ((drawRect.right - drawRect.left) / 2);
int yMiddle = drawRect.top + ((drawRect.bottom - drawRect.top) / 2);

resizeDrawableWidth.setBounds(left - widthWidth,
    yMiddle - widthHeight,
    left + widthWidth,
    yMiddle + widthHeight);
resizeDrawableWidth.draw(canvas);

resizeDrawableWidth.setBounds(right - widthWidth,
    yMiddle - widthHeight,
    right + widthWidth,
    yMiddle + widthHeight);
resizeDrawableWidth.draw(canvas);

resizeDrawableHeight.setBounds(xMiddle - heightWidth,
    top - heightHeight,
    xMiddle + heightWidth,
    top + heightHeight);
resizeDrawableHeight.draw(canvas);

resizeDrawableHeight.setBounds(xMiddle - heightWidth,
    bottom - heightHeight,
    xMiddle + heightWidth,
    bottom + heightHeight);
resizeDrawableHeight.draw(canvas);
```

[image: Trails when dragging]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call invalidate() method before drawing. This will update the view. Please refer to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Comment: I could swear I did invalidate before drawing :)